Factorial anova results differ in R and SPSS
I am trying to run factorial anova in both SPSS and R but got different results. I convered the iv's into factors too. Any suggestions?
pacman::p_load(foreign, phia, car)
d = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srk7774/data/master/stevensp.174.csv", 
              )
d$facta = as.factor(d$facta)
d$factb = as.factor(d$factb)
d$factc = as.factor(d$factc)
m = lm(score ~ 1  + facta * factb * factc, data = d)
Anova(m, type = 3)
#> Anova Table (Type III tests)
#> 
#> Response: score
#>                    Sum Sq Df F value   Pr(>F)   
#> (Intercept)       120.333  1 13.2883 0.001284 **
#> facta               0.167  1  0.0184 0.893218   
#> factb              13.500  1  1.4908 0.233953   
#> factc              94.889  2  5.2393 0.012940 * 
#> facta:factb         1.333  1  0.1472 0.704566   
#> facta:factc       154.333  2  8.5215 0.001598 **
#> factb:factc        23.111  2  1.2761 0.297399   
#> facta:factb:factc  74.889  2  4.1350 0.028639 * 
#> Residuals         217.333 24                    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Created on 2024-05-29 with reprex v2.0.2


The help file of Anova explains that the default contrasts in R, namely contr.treatment is not sensible in type III ANOVA. So change the contrasts to contr.sum, contr.poly or contr.helmer before fitting the model in R.
